# Find value of constant $n$ and coefficient of $x^2$

Tags: binomial-theorem

The question is this:

> In the expansion of $(3 − 2x)(1 + x/2)^n$, the coefficient of $x$ is $7$. Find the value of the constant $n$ and
>   hence find the coefficient of $x^2$.

If $n$ were given I could have solved it using the binomial theorem but I don't know how to solve problems such as these.

The answer key states this but I cant make any sense of it.

> Term in $x = nx/2$
>   $(3-2x)(1+nx/2+\dots) = 7$
>   $n=6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two terms with the first power of $x$, namely $(-2x)(1)$ and $3 \binom n 1 (\frac x 2)$. So $(-2x)(1)+3 \binom n 1 (\frac x 2)=7x$ which gives $n=6$.

When you expand the power using Binomial Theorem and multiply by $3-2x$ you get the first power of $x$ if you multiply the constant term in $3-2x$ by the coefficient of $x$ in $(1+\frac x 2)^{n}$ or you multiply the constant term in $(1+\frac x 2)^{n}$ by the coefficient of $x$ in $3-2x$.

Comment: Thanks. I had an exam today and it really helped :)